# Java: Sending byte[] with other parameters in HTTP Post

Tags: java, http, post, encryption, arrays

I am working on a Java Client Library for the recently exposed unofficial Snapchat API.  As an aside, the GitHub for my library so far is here: https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap

I have most requests working fine, I can log in, download images, etc.  I am using UniRest for all of those requests so far because I like the simplicity of the API.

I am trying to upload media following the format outlined here: http://gibsonsec.org/snapchat/fulldisclosure/#uploading-and-sending-snaps-phupload-phsend

I have no problem generating any of the fields.  The data is a `byte[]` of AES-ECB encrypted data that I read from a file and ran through the specified encryption algorithm.

I have tried a few things:

- Use UniRest's `.field(String name, File file)` method to add the file as a parameter.  I use a temporary Dile I create from the `byte[]`.  This gets me a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` from the server, so I think UniRest is adding some headers I don't want when I do this.
- Serialize the `byte[]` as a `String` using the `String(byte[] bytes, String encoding)` constructor with the `UTF-8` encoding.  This gets me a `500 SERVER ERROR`.
- Not send the `data` field at all, just to see what happens.  This gets me a `400 BAD REQUEST`.

If you look at the `upload` method in the Python library `pysnap` (init.py">https://github.com/martinp/pysnap/blob/master/pysnap/**init**.py) you can see that what I am trying to do has been done before very simply with Python's `requests` library.  I can't figure out how to get the same behavior in Java.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you need to encode the `byte[]` data as a string using base-64 encoding. Try using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary` or a third-party library for base-64.

Converting to a string using `String(byte[] bytes, String encoding)` is completely different.

Comment: Didn't work either, still a 500.  Wish the server would give better errors.  Why did you assume that the server would expect base 64?  Is that something you know about Snapchat or just an assumption made across the web?

Comment: @hatboysam - The [Snapchat docs](http://gibsonsec.org/snapchat/fulldisclosure/#encryptingdecrypting-data) on encrypted data show code for decrypting. Perhaps I misread the docs, however, and it may only apply to stories, not media. It might be instructive to see how the author implemented upload in PHP ([here](https://github.com/nykac/snaphax/blob/master/snaphax.php#L142)).

Comment: Pretty sure my encryption works because I can properly decrypt snaps and the only difference in Java between encrypting and decrypting is `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` vs `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`.

This is the problem with using unofficial APIs ... too hard to debug.

Comment: @hatboysam - I thought the PHP client implementation would be useful not because of the encryption but because of how it structures the HTTP transaction. It apparently writes the encrypted data to a temp file and then points to that file as a field for the upload.

Comment: Ah ok.  I tried that with UniRest I'll try it with Apache HTTP Client maybe.